# Merge list and lists tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think the [list](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) and [lists](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) should be merged: they both share the same tag wiki and I can't imagine that these are needed separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wish granted!

> **Merge Results**
>
> updating post history, 167 rows affected
> updating posts, 120 rows affected
> updating PostTags associations, 120 rows affected
> removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
> updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
> tag remapping of [lists] and [list] complete!
> remapping 0 synonyms
> 3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
> Broadcasting tag-engine reload

I went with the Plural [lists](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) to be the master rather than the singular version.